# How can I generate a form with days of months for the current year in Angular?

Tags: angular

H! I am trying to find a way to generate a calendar in something like a form group where all the information in 365 days will be filled. So far I have this

```
createCalendarForm() {
      this.calendarForm = this.formBuilder.group(
        {
        0: [''],
        1: [''],
        2: [''],
        3: [''],
        4: [''],
        5: [''],
        6: [''],
        7: [''],
        8: [''],
        9: [''],
        10: [''],
        11: [''],
        12: [''],
        13: [''],
        14: [''],
        15: [''],
        16: [''],
        17: [''],
        18: [''],
        19: [''],
        20: [''],
        21: [''],
        22: [''],
        23: [''],
        24: [''],
        25: [''],
        26: [''],
        27: [''],
        28: [''],
        29: [''],
        30: [''],
      });
    
  }
```

```
<form [formGroup]="calendarForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmitCalendar()" #resetRulesForm="ngForm">
    <div class="center">
        <div>Room type 1</div>
        <div  *ngFor="let month of test_month_count; index as i">
            <div>{{current_date_test}}</div>

            <div *ngFor="let day of test_days; index as j">{{day}}
                <!-- <input matInput formControlName="{{month}}" [hidden]="true" style="width:37px; height:25px;"  > -->
                <input matInput formControlName="{{ day}}" style="width:37px; height:25px;"  >
            </div>
        </div>
       
        <button style="font-size: large;" data-action='submit' mat-button type="submit">{{"Home.save" | translate}}</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

My form should look something like this https://ru.nobiarts.com/calendar/555.html.
Clearly I can do it by just hardcoding 365 days but realistically that's a horrible idea and I'm trying to find a way to do this properly.
I've tried using for loops, passing arguments to createCalendarForm function, so far no luck, if you've got any ideas any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 2):

If you need to have 365 controls, you can do something like this:

```
createCalendarForm() {
  const calendarFormData = {};
  for (const key of Array.from(Array(365).keys())) {
    calendarFormData[key] = [''];
  }

  this.calendarForm = this.formBuilder.group(calendarFormData);
  console.log(Object.keys(this.calendarForm.controls).length); // logs 365
}
```

If you haven't already, I'd suggest taking a look at the different kinds of forms you can build [here](https://angular.io/guide/typed-forms). I believe `FormArray` is best suited in your case since you have an array of days.

Comment: Thank you for a reply, to keep it very short I'm trying to make a calendar form just like this using Angular , https://ru.nobiarts.com/calendar/555.html , am I at least on the right track?

Comment: I'd say you are. Looking at the calendar, it seems each day is associated with a quantity and a price, which are the inputs. In that case, I'd create a `FormGroup` for each day (instead of a string) with qty and price as controls. That way, you can assign a control to each qty and price input and add validation to those inputs if you need to.

Comment: Thank you again! I think I get what you are saying, my main issue is that I have a hard time figuring out how to put all of that into code, there are probably ready made examples, I just couldn't find any

Comment: No problem and thanks for my first upvote! Not sure how much progress you already have, but I'd start by looping through each day in the template and then creating the qty and price inputs for each day. You will then be able to get the controls for those inputs with the day number, which would look something like `calendarForms.controls[day].controls.qty`. If you decide to use a `FormArray` instead, you could loop through it (with `calendarForms.values` assuming `calendarForms` is the `FormArray`) and get the `FormGroup` for each day, which would have the qty and price controls.

Comment: I have some progress, but its been getting stuck, is there a way to contact you so I can show you a code ? Can't really write comments with code

Comment: Sorry for the late response. If you still need help and you have Discord, you can send me a DM at jivanf#4896.

Comment: One last thing. I made a mistake in my previous comment, you get the controls in a `FormArray` with the `controls` property, not `values`. Also, if you're interested, you can read more about how to use `FormArray` [here](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-form-array/).